# How can I enable SSE3 in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sse

I'm trying to build some c++ code that uses SSE3 on a mac; the other intrinsic functions are all being pulled in via `#include <x86intrin.h>`, but the SSE3 version `tmmintrin.h` is not, because SSE is apparently not enabled (`__SSSE3__` not defined). In particular, I am looking for `_mm_shuffle_epi*` and `_mm_hadd_epi*`. I'm quite new to both intrinsics and mac, so maybe I'm missing something.

So ideally: How can I get my program to compile on Xcode 6 using the SSE3 intrinsic functions?

As backup: What SSE2 functions can I use in lieu of the aforementioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the code generation option for vector instructions in your build settings:

[image]

In this example SSSE3 (and below) are enabled.

Note that you seem to be confused between SSE3 and SSSE3 (aka "SSE3 with supplemental instructions" or "MNI") - note the difference.

Comment: This looks like what I need (will mark). However, I don't see this build setting in my project; might this be because it's an iOS project? (I only want SSE for the emulator version, which I don't believe has the NEON instructions available).

Comment: OK, that's a different question then - type "vector" in the build settings search box to see what options are available, but I don't even know if this is possible for an iOS project.